# GRE 9378 question 23

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, gre-exam

Let $f$ be a real valued function continuous on the closed interval $[0,1]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(0,1)$, with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. Which of the following must be true?

1. There exists $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x)=x$.
2. There exists $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(x)=-1$.
3. $f(x)>0 $ for all  $x \in [0,1)$

I think the solution is `1 only`, but apparently is `1 and 2 only`.
I don't see why 2 is true, if the derivative of $f$ is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Wow. I was confused for a very long time. You're 2 is not on a new line, and then the one below it is labeled 2, so I was missing the real 2 and looking at 3 thinking that it is clearly false. I'll edit that I guess...OK, actually already done by MJD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a direct application of the mean value theorem, which does not require $f'$ to be continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(x)=f(x)+x$. Note that $g(0)=g(1)=1$.

If $g(x)$ is identically equal to $1$, there is nothing to prove.

If $g(x)$ is not identically equal to $1$, then $g$ attains a local maximum or minimum in $(0,1)$. There we have $g'(x)=0$.

**Remark:** Even MVT was not used, though admittedly the crucial component of the proof of MVT was.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative may not be continuous, but it does have the Intermediate Value Property.

Comment: How does this help? We aren't given values of $f'$.

Comment: Can you show it's impossible for $f'\gt-1$ for all $x$? ditto, $f'\lt-1$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 1):

**Direct application of mean value theorem.**

It is differentiable in open interval $(0, 1)$. Hence it is continuous too. So no matter what the graph is, it will have some point where the slope would be $-1$.

From $x=0$ to $x=1$, you have to connect $(0, 1)$ (as `f(0)=1`) and $(1, 0)$ (as `f(1)=0`).

You can consider some cases to do so.

**Case 1**:

A curve first going up, then coming down. So while coming down, it will have `-1` slope somewhere

**Case 2**

A curve first going down, then coming up. While going down, it will have `-1` slope somewhere

**Case 3**

A straight line connect the two points. Clearly, it has a slope of `-1`

So, 2$^{nd}$ must be true.
There can be infinite curves. I've explained just three.

While doing the question, if you can't figure it out, just try to search for a contradicting example.